# Add 30 to the formula in a cell

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I need your help.
in a sheet, in the C7 cell i have a date.In D7 by default, the formula is C7+30. I need a code who will add 30 to the formula  D7. if i run thre code once, the formula in  D7 should become C7+30+30. if i run the code again, the code should be C7+30+30+30, and so on. Each time i run the code to the formula in D7, it should add 30. Could you help me please?

I've tried to modify the formula , but it works only the first time, it transforms the formula  in C7+30+30, but if i run the code again, the formula stays the same C7+30+30. I dont't know to "loop"it

Comment: Please include the code you're using.

Comment: I don't think you need a loop. You just need some code like `Sheet1.Range("C7").Formula = Sheet1.Range("C7").Formula & "+30"`

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use a formula that references a cell that holds the value to add?  Then all you have to do is increment that value in one place.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Out of interest, why do you need to do this? Why change the formula and not just have a cell with "iteration" being an integer? Suppose that integer is in E7, then Then D7 =C7+30*E7

Comment: This is a [X/Y-Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You ask X but your actual issue is Y. Please make sure you [edit] your question and explain what you are actually trying to do and why you think adding +30 to the formula would be the solution to that.

Answer (score 2):

```
Sub add30()
    Range("D7").Formula = Range("D7").Formula & "+30"
End Sub
```